# How we obtain this limit on an integral?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces

For a squence $(u_n)\subset W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $(y_n)\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ we have that for a subseuqnce  $|y_n|<M$ then

What we use to prove that 
$$
\limsup_{n\to+\infty}\int_{B_{r+M}(0)} |u_n(x)|^p dx\geq \limsup_{n\to+\infty}\int_{B_r(y_n)}|u_n(x)|^p dx
$$

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We have $B_{r}(y_{n})\subseteq B_{r+M}(0)$: For $z\in B_{r}(y_{n})$, then $|z-y_{n}|<r$, so $|z|\leq|z-y_{n}|+|y_{n}|<r+M$, so $z\in B_{r+M}(0)$.

So
\begin{align*}
\int_{B_{r}(y_{n})}|u_{n}(x)|^{p}dx\leq\int_{B_{r+M}(0)}|u_{n}(x)|^{p}dx,
\end{align*}
now taking $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ both sides.

Comment: please what is the difference between passing to the limit and the lim sup ?

Comment: $\lim$ does not necessarily exist in this case but $\limsup$ must exist so you can use $\limsup$.

Comment: why lim sup exist in this case please ? and what we must have to get that the lim exist ?

Comment: For a sequence $(a_{n})$, $\limsup a_{n}$ exists since it is defined as monotone sequences $\limsup a_{n}=\inf_{n}\sup_{k\geq n}a_{n}$, the value could be $\infty$ or $-\infty$, so precisely speaking, we should say it must exist in the extended real sense. $\lim$ exists if and only if $\limsup=\liminf$.